# releasing memory in sub-function

Tags: programming, sd-card, memory-usage, code-optimization

I'm doing a program who get a line from the SD and shows it, this function is called *getData()*

FULL CODE:

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <MemoryFree.h>

File myFile;
int stringIndex = 0;
int cursorPosition = 0;
char inputString [25];
char inputChar;
boolean endOfLine;
char fullPath[11];

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.print("Initializing SD card.");
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);

  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

}

void loop(){

  Serial.println(getDataSD());

  Serial.print("freeMemory()=");
  Serial.println(freeMemory());
}

String getDataSD(){

  memset(inputString, 0, sizeof(inputString));

  getFileNameSD();

  myFile = SD.open(fullPath);

  if(myFile){
    myFile.seek(cursorPosition);

    endOfLine = false;    

    while(myFile.available() && endOfLine == false){
      inputChar = myFile.read();

      if(inputChar == '*'){
        while(inputChar != '\n'){
          inputChar = myFile.read();
        }
      }else{
        cursorPosition = myFile.position()-1;

        if(inputChar == 10 || inputChar == ' ') inputChar = myFile.read();

        while(inputChar != '\n'){
          if(stringIndex < 25){          
            inputString[stringIndex] = inputChar;
            stringIndex++;
            inputChar = myFile.read();
          }
        }
        inputString[stringIndex-1] = '\0';        
        stringIndex    = 0;
        endOfLine      = true;        
      }      
    }
    myFile.close();    
  }
  return inputString;
}

void getFileNameSD (){

  char folder[] = "/ACC";

  checkFolderSD(folder);  

  myFile = SD.open(folder);
  myFile = myFile.openNextFile();

  if(!myFile) myFile.rewindDirectory();

  if(myFile){

    strcpy(fullPath,folder);
    strcat(fullPath,"/");
    strcat(fullPath,myFile.name());

    myFile.close();
  }
}
```

I don't have problem with this function(getDataSD). To get the name of the file, I've created another function who looks for a file in a specific folder, this function is called *getFileNameSD()*

I'm having problem with this last function, it's not releasing or overwriting some data, so every time it's called, it is stored new data in memory

I've included the [memory Free library](http://github.com/maniacbug/MemoryFree) to see where is the problem. When I call the *getDataSD* and write the file manually I dont have problem.

```
myFile = SD.open("/ACC/11001");
```

Serial monitor

```
freeMemory()=6592
/-27/-26/-56/
freeMemory()=6592
/-27/-26/-56/
freeMemory()=6592
/-27/-26/-56/
freeMemory()=6592
/-27/-26/-56/
freeMemory()=6592
/-27/-26/-56/
freeMemory()=6592
/-27/-26/-56/
```

the memory always is the same.

but not when I call the *getFileNameSD()*

```
myFile = SD.open(getFileNameSD());
```

Serial monitor

```
freeMemory()=6571
/-27/-26/-56/
freeMemory()=6540
/-27/-26/-56/
freeMemory()=6509
/-27/-26/-56/
freeMemory()=6478
/-27/-26/-56/
freeMemory()=6447
/-27/-26/-56/
```

I know I'm doing something wrong with *getFileName()* but I don't know what is, can anybody help/explain me?

Comment: Where did you declare and define `fullPath`?

Comment: sorry about that, was typo, I corrected the first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally someone found where was the problem.
In the *getFileName()* function, I open two instances of the file but I close just one.

here is the answer:

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <MemoryFree.h>

File myFile;
int stringIndex = 0;
int cursorPosition = 0;
char inputString [25];
char inputChar;
boolean endOfLine;
char fullPath[11];

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.print("Initializing SD card.");
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);

  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

}

void loop(){

  Serial.println(getDataSD());

  Serial.print("freeMemory()=");
  Serial.println(freeMemory());
}

void getDataSD(){

  memset(inputString, 0, sizeof(inputString));

  getFileNameSD();

  myFile = SD.open(fullPath);

  if(myFile){
    myFile.seek(cursorPosition);

    endOfLine = false;    

    while(myFile.available() && endOfLine == false){
      inputChar = myFile.read();

      if(inputChar == '*'){
        while(inputChar != '\n'){
          inputChar = myFile.read();
        }
      }else{
        cursorPosition = myFile.position()-1;

        if(inputChar == 10 || inputChar == ' ') inputChar = myFile.read();

        while(inputChar != '\n'){
          if(stringIndex < 25){          
            inputString[stringIndex] = inputChar;
            stringIndex++;
            inputChar = myFile.read();
          }
        }
        inputString[stringIndex-1] = '\0';        
        stringIndex    = 0;
        endOfLine      = true;        
      }      
    }
    myFile.close();    
  }
}

void getFileNameSD (){

  char folder[] = "/ACC";
  File myDir = SD.open(folder);

  memset(fullPath, 0, sizeof(fullPath));

  if (myDir){
    myFile = myDir.openNextFile();

    if(myFile){
      strcpy(fullPath,folder);
      strcat(fullPath,"/");
      strcat(fullPath,myFile.name());
      myFile.close();
      myDir.close();
    }else{
      // Handle file not found
      myDir.close();
      fullPath[0] = '0';
    }
  }else{
    // Handle directory not opened
    fullPath[0] = '0';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

I don't know, why your memory is leaking, but anyway, your program won't work safely. 
You defined an array (fullPath) inside the local scope of your function. You return it, which means, you return a pointer to this array. But at the same time, this array gets invalid, because you leave the local scope of your function.

Better define that string outside the function and give it as a parameter to the function. Then you aren't in danger of accessing an invalid pointer. Furthermore your memory leak won't appear.

Comment: thanks for the advice Arister, I've edited the code to fix that problem, unfortunately it didn't solved my problem.